# How to set shopify order to fulfilled?

Tags: python, curl, request, shopify, shopify-api

**Set-up**

I have a Shopify store with an unfulfilled order and have access to the store's REST API.

The order has been shipped and I have its `tracking_number`, `tracking_url` and the `transport_company`.

I want to use the REST API to set the order to fulfilled and send the `tracking_number`, `tracking_url` and `transport_company` info to the customer.

---

**Code**

I have the order's id in Shopify, the `order_id`, such that I can get the order's `fulfillment_orders` item and from there the `fulfillment_id` and `location_id` like so,

```
fulfillment_orders = requests.get(shop_url + '/orders/'+ order_id +'/fulfillment_orders.json').json()   
fulfillment_id = str(fulfillment_orders['fulfillment_orders'][0]['id'])
location_id = requests.get(shop_url + '/locations.json').json()['locations'][0]['id']
```

where `shop_url` is the url needed to connect to the store.

So far the code works.

Then, I set up the payload,

```
payload = {
    "fulfillment": 
        {            
        "notify_customer": 'false',
        "location_id": location_id,        
        "tracking_info":{                
            "tracking_url": tracking_url,
            "tracking_company": transport_company,
            "tracking_number": tracking_number,            
            }
        }
    }
```

where `location_id` is an integer and the other variables are strings.

When I subsequently run the following request to insert the information into the order,

```
r = requests.post(shop_url + '/fulfillments/' + fulfillment_id + '/update_tracking.json',
                 json=payload,headers=headers)
```

I get a `<Response [400]>`.

---

**Question**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to do it is [discussed here](https://shopify.dev/apps/fulfillment/order-management-apps).

Assuming you have the shopify order id `order_id` and the `shop_url`, the following code will set an order as fulfilled,

```
# get order fulfillment id 
fulfillment_orders = requests.get(shop_url + '/orders/'+ order_id +'/fulfillment_orders.json').json()     
fulfillment_id = fulfillment_orders['fulfillment_orders'][0]['id']
location_id = requests.get(shop_url + '/locations.json').json()['locations'][0]['id']   

# get orders fulfillment line items 

# note: if you want to fulfill only certain products in the order with the tracking code,
# here's where you select these products. Right now, the code isn't doing this 

fulfillment_order_line_items = []

for item in fulfillment_orders['fulfillment_orders'][0]['line_items']:
    
    fulfillment_order_line_items.append(
            {
            'id': item['id'],
            'quantity': item['quantity'],
            }
        )         

# set up payload
payload = {
    "fulfillment": 
        {            
            "notify_customer": 'false',
            "location_id": location_id,        
            "tracking_info":
                {                
                "url": tracking_url,
                "company": transport_company,
                "number": tracking_number,            
                },
            "line_items_by_fulfillment_order": [
                {
                    "fulfillment_order_id": fulfillment_id,
                    "fulfillment_order_line_items": fulfillment_order_line_items
                }
            ]            
        }
    }
    
# parse tracking info
r = requests.post(shop_url + '/fulfillments.json',
                 json=payload,headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a mix of solutions the accepted answer sadly didnt work straight away for me.

First of all you need the fulfillments of a given order - this is the endpoint:

```
GET  https://<<YOUR-SHOP>>/admin/api/2022-04/orders/<<ORDER-ID>>/fulfillment_orders.json?status=open
```

Be aware there can be **more than one** fulfillment per order. I recommend to use the **status=open** flag. Otherwise you also get previously closed fulfillments like e.g. if you fulfilled it earlier and set it back to unfulfilled. Since they are closed I wouldn't request them. Funfact you can't open this endpoint via Firefox use chrome or a real api platform instead.

```
GET  https://<<YOUR-SHOP>>/admin/api/2022-04/locations.json
```

You get the Location ID from this endpoint.

Here comes the next pitfal. For me it was not enough to simply call `api/orders/fulfillments.json`. I had to provide the `ORDER-ID` again like in the first call.

```
POST  https://<<YOUR-SHOP>>/admin/api/2022-04/orders/<<ORDER-ID>>/fulfillments.json
```

This is the payload:

```
{
  "fulfillment": {
    "line_items_by_fulfillment_order": [
      {
        "fulfillment_order_id": "5859341008918",
        "fulfillment_order_line_items": [
          {
            "id": "12675478814742",
            "quantity": "3"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "tracking_info": {
      "number": "1234",
      "url": "www.usps.com",
      "company": "Fake Company"
    },
    "notify_customer": false,
    "origin_address": null,
    "message": "test message"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think they recently removed the `/admin/api/2022-04/orders/<<ORDER-ID>>/fulfillments.json` endpoint. I'm using api version 2023-04, and I was able to get it working with the `'/admin/api/'+api_version+'/fulfillments.json'` endpoint mentioned in the accepted answer.

Comment: They want to remove the old legacy fulfillment api process. I think the old way didnt use the fulfillment_orders.json to get a fulfillment and it was a different endpoint. For me its still working right now but they want to shut it down next month so I might update.